# Handling both clicks and keypresses in React number input not working

Tags: javascript, reactjs, input, state

I have part of some React code below, where I have a number input, I'd like to prevent people being able to click below 0, which I've done with the min attribute. However I've seen that it's possible to still manually key in negative numbers. After some googling I've seen that people can handle this with a keyPress check and looking at the character codes but for some reason I can't quite get this to work.

Are both handlers clashing with each other? My goal is to allow click increments to work for positive numbers and prevent negative and decimal numbers being allowed in the input.

It's a controlled input, where value is coming from state.

```
const handleChange = (e) => {
    console.log(e.target.value);
    setCount(e.target.value);
  };

  const handleKeyPress = (e) => {
    console.log(e.target.value);
    console.log(e.charCode);
    if (e.charCode >= 48 && e.charCode <= 57) {
      setCount(e.target.value);
    }
  };

  return (
    <section>
      <h3>Input test</h3>
      <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
        <label htmlFor="amount">paragraphs:</label>
        <input
          type="number"
          name="amount"
          id="amount"
          min="0"
          value={count}
          onKeyPress={handleKeyPress}
          onChange={handleChange}
        />
```

Answer (score 0):

You can format your value to absolute integer in your handleChange function and it would remove the zero and decimal separator on re-render:

```
const handleChange = (e) => {
  setCount(Math.abs(parseInt(e.target.value)));
};
```

Or if you absolutely want to prevent "0" and "." characters to be entered, you can use preventDefault in your handleKeyPress function:

```
const handleKeyPress = (e) => {
  if (e.charCode === 45 || e.charCode === 46) {
    return e.preventDefault()
  }
};
```

Comment: I'd like to restrict negative numbers or decimal numbers being entered by keypress if thats possible. I'm allowed to use both handlers combined together i.e. onChange and onKeyPress or do they end up clashing?

Comment: I know preventDefault can stop a page refresh but how does it work here on the keyPress? can you explain please.

Comment: preventDefault prevents the page from refreshing when used with 'submit' which is usually a default event type for the form element. In this context when it's used with the 'keyPress', it prevents another action which is launching text composition system for the specific key.

Comment: what do you mean by text composition system? I didn't understand.

Comment: Also is it ok to use different handlers on the same input? e.g. onChange and onKeyPress?

Comment: It should be fine to use different event handlers as long as your logic in those doesn't conflict.

Answer (score 0):

In this case you would like to use `onKeyPress` as a validator only. If validation fails, you can call `e.preventDefault()`. This way it will prevent to trigger `onChange`:

```
  const handleKeyPress = (e) => {
    if (e.charCode >= 48 && e.charCode <= 57) return
    e.preventDefault()
  };
```